# What is local name = value or 0 in lua?

Tags: lua

What does this block of code do?

```
local name = value or 0
```

Please tell me that it makes it zero if nil and makes it value if not nil.

Comment: Yes, that is what it does. It also sets to 0 if false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

yes

## Looooong answer

You're right. While in other languages, the logical operators return either `true` or `false`, Lua (and some other languages) does something more clever:

When the first parameter of `or` is truthy, it evaluates to that value, if it's not, it evaluates to the second one. And does it the other way around: if its left-hand-side is falsey, it evaluates to that, otherwise it evaluates to its RHS.

Logically, this means that `or` evaluates to truthy if either operand is truthy and `and` evaluates to falsey if either of its operands is.

This is often used as an equivalent of

```
if value then
  name = value
else
  name = 0
end
```

And it effectively does the same. It is also often use to assign default values to variables like this:

```
function call(name)
  name = name or "you"
  print("Hey "..name.."! Come here for a moment!")
end
```

Note though, that this doesn't work

```
function alarm(real)
  real = real or true
  print "ALAAARM!"
  if real then print "This is NOT a drill!" end
end
alarm(false)
```

This will always print "ALAAARM!" "This is NOT a drill!", because `false` is evaluated as falsey, so the `or` statement evaluates to its RHS, which is `true`. In this particular example, you would have to check explicitly if the argument is nil.

```
-- ...
  real = (real == nil) and true or real
-- ...
```

This would work as intended, because only if `real == nil`, the `and` statement evaluates to `true`, and the `or` thus evaluates to its LHS. If `real == nil` is `false`, then the `and` evaluates to that, thus the or statement evaluates to its RHS (because its LHS is `false`).

It's also worth mentioning that both `and` and `or` are short-circuited. What this means is:

```
function foo(bar)
  print(bar)
  return bar
end
io.write "First: "
local A = foo(nil) or foo(false)
io.write "Second: "
local B = foo(true) or foo(true)
```

This will print "First: nil false" on the first two lines, but then "Second: true" on the third line. The last call to `foo` is not even executed, because at that point the `or` statement already knows it's going to return its left operand.

Comment: Thanks­­­­­­­­­­­­